# How can I compare Stanford Core NLP with an algorithm without the trained dataset for the movies?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am looking to use the Stanford Core NLP which is trained for movie reviews. I want to compare it with a regular sentiment analysis algorithm which is untrained for movie reviews. Is there a way to use the Stanford Core NLP [Link Here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html) without the trained dataset for the movie reviews or is there any other source I can use to compare directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by CoreNLP Sentiment without a trained movie review dataset. The Sentiment model needs some dataset to train on -- untrained it will simply not do anything. It is possible to train it on a dataset which is not movie reviews, but for this you'd have to find or create a suitable dataset.

Comment: I understand that. I mean to say are there any direct bag of words or positive / negative word list sentiment analysis from open source that I can compare with directly?

Comment: Bag of words also needs a training set. Naive Bayes with bigram features is actually surprisingly strong (see Sida Wang's paper on sentiment analysis: http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/sidaw12_simple_sentiment.pdf). For something completely untrained, you can look at resources like the Harvard Inquirer. On their own, these are not expected to perform well though.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any particular open source software or any particular github project that is based on such Naive Bayes algorithm with bigram features that I can use to compare the results with trained CoreNLP for movie reviews? Sorry if the question is a little noob-ish.

Comment: Sida's Naive Bayes code is up at https://github.com/sidaw/nbsvm. There are also comparisons in various academic papers, if you're running on a standard dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it out and one little question. I'm just starting to learn this. In the Github page, I see they have datasets meaning the SVM algorithm that they have compared with uses the datasets and the Naive Bayes algorithm uses positive and negative wordlists, right I hope?

Comment: Both the svm and Naive Bayes models are trained from a dataset. I don't know of any released sentiment analysis tool that only use word lists.

Comment: Got it, thanks. What I'm trying to learn is whether Naive Bayes or the SVM trained with the same movie review dataset are better when they are tested with something other than the movie reviews such as a new phone review or something else. Does the Naive Bayes algorithm perform better in that respect or does it depend on a variety of factors?

Comment: That's an interesting question! In general, it depends on a variety of factors; you should write up your results and post it somewhere!

Comment: I'll do that and get back to you, thanks for the information so far. I'm low on reputation to contact you over chat directly here. Can I do it any other way in case of any queries? If that's okay with you of course.

Comment: Email is generally preferred anyways. My email is on my Stanford homepage.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can perform Polarity Sentiment Analysis by **VADER: A
   Parsimonious Rule-based Model for Sentiment Analysis of Social Media
   Text**.   This package is using static knowledge base of positive and negative words (lexicon). For each movie review, 4 scores are provided: positive,
   negative, neutral    sentiment scores and also the “compound” score
   (which discriminate between the other three).

See:

https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment

http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html

http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sentiment/vader.html

2. Additional lexicon can be taken from [here](https://github.com/jeffreybreen/twitter-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-201107/tree/master/data/opinion-lexicon-English).
3. As far as I know, CoreNLP provides trained CoreNLP models for English. See [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/#human-languages-supported).

Answer (score 0):

The Stanford CoreNLP API is bundled with pretrained models trained using movie reviews. So you can use the API directly.